# Replace chars in string if it starts or ends with specified char

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a column in my database with entries that starts or ends with a hyphen. I would like to find these rows and remove/replace the hyphens if it's the last or first (or both) char in the string.

What I have now:

```
-sample-value-one-
sample-value-two-
-sample-value-three
sample-value-four
```

And this is what I would like to achieve:

```
sample-value-one
sample-value-two
sample-value-three
sample-value-four
```

So I should have to find all rows which starts or ends with a hyphen, and if there is a match, remove the hyphen while the other hyphens in the string should remain the same.

I don't have problems with replacing one string, but this task seems to be too hard for me.

Comment: Is this something that you want to do one time only, or at regular intervals?  You tagged mysql and also php -- do you have a preference for a MySQL solution or a PHP one?

Comment: @AC Just one time, I would like to do it in phpmyadmin. I didn't tag php. My goal is to do it with sql statement.

Comment: My bad, sometimes I squint and "sql" looks like "php".  Is it always just a *single* hyphen at the beginning and/or end?

Comment: @AC Yes, it's always at the beginning or/and at the end and all entry contains hyphen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's just a single hyphen, then:

```
# Remove first hyphen
update myTable 
set myCol = substr(myCol,2)
where myCol like '-%'
;

# Remove last hyphen
update myTable 
set myCol = substr(myCol,1,length(myCol)-1)
where myCol like '%-'
;
```

Answer (score 2):

could be using like and case

```
update my_table 
set my_column  =  case  when my_column like '-%'  then substr(my_column, 2, LENGTH(my_column)-1 )
                        when my_column like '%-' then substr(my_column, 1, LENGTH(my_column)-1  )
                        when my_column like '-%-'  then  substr(my_column, 2, LENGTH(my_column)-2 )
                  end 
where my_column like '-%'  
or  my_column like '%-' 
or  my_column like '-%-'
```